# Isometry group of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: metric-spaces, lie-groups, group-actions, isometry

Consider the group of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ equipped with the discrete metric
$$d(m, n) = \begin{cases}
1, \quad m \neq n\\
0 , \quad m = n
\end{cases}$$
In particular, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a metric Lie group with left-invariant metric $d$.

I would like to study the action of $\text{Iso}(\mathbb{Z})$ on $\mathbb{Z}$
$$\text{Iso}(\mathbb{Z}) \, \times \, \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}, \quad (F, \, m) \, \mapsto \, F(m),$$
where $\text{Iso}(\mathbb{Z})$ is the isometry group of $\mathbb{Z}$.

I'm not able to visualize in a concrete way what gives $\text{Iso}(\mathbb{Z})$ in this context in order to try after to prove a result about the stabilizers of $\text{Iso}(\mathbb{Z})$.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't $\text{Iso}(\mathbb Z)$ just the group of all *permutations* of $\mathbb Z$? As the metric is discrete, any bijection on $\mathbb Z$ is an isometry. Does it help?

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes thanks! I'm just a little bit confusing about the topology. If $\text{Iso}(\mathbb{Z})$ is equipped with the compact-open topology, then the compact sets in the subbase are just finite subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Correct, a topological space with discrete topology is compact if and only if it is finite. (Otherwise, the open cover consisting of the $1$-element subsets won't have a finite subcover.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop The whole permutation group is the isometry group here, but this is not true for every discrete metric.

Comment: @userr777 the compact-open topology here is reasonable. A basis of neighborhoods of $\mathrm{id}$ is given by the pointwise stabilizers of finite subsets (which are subgroups).

Comment: @StinkingBishop On the set $\{0,1,2\}$ with $d(0,1)=d(1,2)=1$, $d(0,2)=2$. Maybe you have a more restricted definition in mind of "discrete metric"; I understand it as "defining the discrete topology".

Comment: @YCor I seem to have had a temporary instance of brain fog. Thanks. (On a second look, true, a discrete metric is sometimes considered to be the one having only values $0$ and $1$: see e.g. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteMetric.html )

Comment: @StinkingBishop Sorry, another related question. In this case, is $S_{\mathbb{Z}}$ a Lie group?

Comment: @userr777 You cannot ask if a group is a Lie group. A Lie group is a group with additional structure (in this case a structure of a differentiable manifold). To me, it is akin to asking a question "Is the set $\{1,2,3\}$ a group?". I don't know - show me the additional operations on it, and I will be able to tell you if they satisfy the group axioms. Similarly here - what is the differentiable manifold structure on $S_{\mathbb Z}$ you want to consider? Or, a more basic question: what topology on $S_{\mathbb Z}$ you want to consider? (If it is discrete, then obviously it cannot be a manifold.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop I forgot to mention that $S_{\mathbb{Z}}$ is equipped with the compact-open topology, where $\mathbb{Z}$ is equipped with the discrete metric. I apologize for this.

Comment: That is above my knowledge so I can only give you an educated guess. I believe the set $C(\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z)$ of all continuous maps (i.e. all maps!) of $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$, with compact-open topology, is homeomorphic to a Cartesian product of countably many copies of $\mathbb Z$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology#Properties ). As such, as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space#Properties, it is totally disconnected, and so its subset $S_{\mathbb Z}$ is totally disconnected. On the other hand, manifolds cannot be totally disconnected.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I really appreciated you help, many thanks!!